# Как удалить все точки, кроме одной (regexp)?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, как удалить все точки, кроме одной, используя `str.replace(regexp, '')`, например,

```
'12..1.1..1.1...1' => '12.11111'
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Так например это можно сделать:

```
'12..1.1..1.1...1'.replace(/^([^.]*?\.[^.]*?)\.|([^.]*?)\./g, '$1$2')
```

## Некроапдейт

Мое внимание привлек этот вопрос, так как совсем недавно (спустя три года) ТС принял ответ на него. В связи с этим решил улучшить качество ответа:

```js
result = '12..1.1..1.1...1'.replace( /^([^\.]*\.)|\./g, '$1' );
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Регулярное выражение за три года стало значительно проще и понятнее.

Comment: апнул ответ, так что улучшай еще раз

Answer (score 2):

А если так:

```
var str = "12..1.1..1.1...1";
    var arr = str.split(".");
    str = arr[0]+"."+arr.slice(1).join("");
```